# React dynamic routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react app which work like this:

- Data is coming from backend. Data structure is like tree (category and subcategories).
- Base on each category and subcategories, a route is created with their slug.
- Each category can have a page which if does, it should go to the page
- Each page has a route that its slug is coming from backend.
- Each page can have a reference to another page as a child page

My question is how can I inject routes in react dynamically (whether with `react-router` or anything else) based on data that I can't get when creating routing.

A key part is user can share a link with others and they should see relevant category or page, for example `"/news/how-to-react/2023-react-with-typescript"`.

In this scenario `"news"` and `"how-to-react"` are category and subcategory which `"how-to-react"` reference to a page with type blog on that page there is post which gives us final route. If the route was shared with others, it should render post.

I have tried using `"/*"` as a child of each subcategory (which I can get at beginning of app loading), but got some errors due to limitations of `react-router`.

Exmaple:

We have a category with subCategoories:

```
| Category 1
| | Category 1.1
| | Category 1.2
| 
| Category 2
| | Category 2.1
| | | Category 2.1.1
| | | | Category 2.1.1.1
```

(basically a one to many self referenced category)
These categories are created dynamically and each one may have an associate page with different types (like BLOG, CONTENT, PDF, etc.) with a slug.
In this case `Category 2.1` and `Category 2.1.1.1` have page. the route to their page must be

```
Category 2.1     -> /category_2/category_2_1/:pageSlug
Category 2.1.1.1 -> /category_2/category_2_1/category_2_1_1/category_2_1_1/:pageSlug
```

Consider page for `Category 2.1` is like blog (has many post) and each post has a slug. So if user wants to see post, should redirect to route `/category_2/category_2_1/:pageSlug/:postSlug`

My question is how can a anticipate these routes without knowing what they are and render appropriate page base on page type

App.tsx:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      {parentCategoriesWithAllSubs
        .map((category) => DynamicCategoriesRoute(category))
        .flat()
        .map((c) => (
          <Route
            key={`route-${c.id}`}
            path={c.route}
            element={<DynamicPage />}
          />
        ))}
      {/* 404 */}
      <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

`DynamicCategoriesRoute(category)` will return an array with routes of all subCategories. In Above example `DynamicCategoriesRoute(category)` would return:

```js
[
    [
        "category_1",
        "category_1/category_1_1",
        "category_1/category_1_2"
    ],
    [
        "category_2",
        "category_2_1",
        "category_2_1_1",
        "category_2_1_1_1"
    ]
]
```

DynamicPage.tsx:

```
export const DynamicPage = () => {
  const url = window.location.pathname;
  const { page } = useGetPageByURL(url);

  if (page.type === "CONTENT") {
    return <ContentPage />;
  } else if (page.type === "BLOG") {
    return <BlogPage />;
  } else if (page.type === "PDF") {
    return <PDFPage />
  }

  return <div>Bad Page TYPE</div>
}
```

Here is schema representation of database and relatoins:
[image: Database Schema]

Comment: Instead of trying to dynamically generate static routes to match *some* specific data, make the routes generic and capable of matching routes dynamically, e.g. `path="/:category/:subCategory/:id"`.

Comment: @DrewReese the depth of category and subcategories are not static. in a scenario I might have `path="/:category/:subCategory1/subCategory2/.../:slug`

Comment: Is there an issue with declaring as many dynamic paths as you need? Can you [edit] the post to clearly define the use case, explain what is or isn't working as expected, and include a [mcve] for what you are trying to do since we can't address issues in code we can't see?

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry for that, Updated.

Comment: Is there a limit to the "depth" of a category's sub-categories? If there isn't a limit, or there is but it's unwieldy in URL path form, you might want to reconsider how you think about this content in terms of how a user accesses 1 single specific document, or how one specific document relates to another specific document.

Comment: @DrewReese there is no limit. how would you suggest to access the document?

Comment: It *looks* like everything goes "through" Page, maybe a URL path that uses a document type and GUID? Example: `"/page/:docType/:docId"`.